# Is it possible to show console.log messages as they occur in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, console, firefox-developer-tools, google-developers-console

I have a JS script I have been trying to debug.  It works fine.  It has alerts, prompts, and console.log messages.  I noticed in Firefox the console.log messages get printed to console "live" as they occur in the script, yet in Chrome, one has to wait until the script has completed before the console.log messages get shown.  This behavior made me think it was a bug or that I had simply clicked the wrong filter or option.

I'm still not sure why Chrome behaves the way it does.

Any insights?  I would prefer to see messages occur as they are happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After hours of fiddling about, I figured out the culprit.  Chrome can indeed show console messages as they are occurring.  Apparently, the "Pause on caught exceptions" option was turned on by accident and had stopped the log from showing up.

If anybody else has this problem ... you will need to wait until the script finishes and click on one of the messages.  In my case, it was "bs.js".  From there you will see an option "Pause on caught exceptions" where you can toggle the option.  Hope this helps someone.  [image: screenshot of Chrome Console options]